# While Loop Complications

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm writing a python program based on the Accordion style of solitaire. I've written the above code and have been playing around with it for the last couple hours but I can't seem to make the loop run correctly. For whatever reason it will either run through the loop only once and not ask for input again, or it will run through once, ask input, and no matter what I input it crashes. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
import random

print("Command Options:")
print("1C - Play card C onto pile 1 position back, ignored if invalid")
print("3C - Play card C onto pile 3 positions back, ignored if invalid")
print("C - Count of undealt cards")
print("D - Deal next card")
print("H - Print this help screen")
print("R - Resign this game (quit early)")
print("X - Exit Program")

cards=['AC','2C','3C','4C','5C','6C','7C','8C','9C','TC','JC','QC','KC','AD','2D','3D','4D','5D','6D','7D','8D','9D','TD','JD','QD','KD','AH','2H','3H','4H','5H','6H','7H','8H','9H','TH','JH','QH','KH','AS','2S','3S','4S','5S','6S','7S','8S','9S','TS','JS','QS','KS']
random.shuffle(cards,random.random)

playable=[]
done=False
while not done:
    move=input("Enter move: ")
    move_upper=move.upper()
    if move_upper == 'D':
        playable.append(cards.pop())
        print(playable)
    if move_upper == 'X' or 'R':
        done=True

    if move_upper == 'H':
        print("Command Options:")
        print("1C - Play card C onto pile 1 position back, ignored if invalid")
        print("3C - Play card C onto pile 3 positions back, ignored if invalid")
        print("C - Count of undealt cards")
        print("D - Deal next card")
        print("H - Print this help screen")
        print("R - Resign this game (quit early)")
        print("X - Exit Program")
    if move_upper == 'C':
        k=0
        for item in cards:
            k+=1
            print(K,'cards left')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how `or` works. Use:

```
if move_upper in ('X', 'R'):
```

instead.

The expression `move_upper == 'X' or 'R'` is interpreted as `(move_upper == 'X') or 'R'` instead, and an non-empty string is *always* considered `True`. Thus, you were in essence testing for `(move_upper == 'X') or True`, and then it doesn't matter anymore what `move_upper` is, really.

You don't really need to use a `done` flag variable here; use `break` to end the loop instead:

```
while True:
    # ...

    if move_upper in ('X', 'R'):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a code-review mood currently, so please forgive me.

```
cards = [ number + suite for number in 'A23456789TJQK' for suite in 'CDHS' ]
```

is more readable and this way the likelihood of bugs in there is reduced.